# Connecting to Exchange Web Server (EWS) by using the EWS Managed API 2.2 from mac

Tags: macos, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, credentials

We are trying to connected to EWS programmatically using EWS Managed API 2.2.

Till Mac Os 10.12,  we were able to use

`//Connect by using the default credentials of the authenticated 
 user.
service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
service.EnableScpLookup = false;`

and

`// Use Autodiscover to set the URL endpoint.
service.AutodiscoverUrl("user1@contoso.com");`

(ref :- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/ff597939(v%3Dexchg.80))

Using this and **without providing the credential explicitly**, we were able to connect to EWS in Mac.

However from 10.13 onwards, 
To connect to EWS, 
this is not working.
Were any of you able to connect the Exchange Server without explicitly providing the credential in the domain managed Mac computers (where user has already logged in).

Comment: If we add 

`Service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email", "password");`

It works with MacOS 10.13 as well. But the whole point of this question is to get way from asking users to provide with the password .

Comment: The problem is most likely your OS configuration I would suggest as a starter https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-mssql/wiki/How-to-enable-Integrated-Authentication-on-macOS-and-Linux-using-Kerberos